# Override playerVars controls:attrib dynamically for videos in youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have below JS code for youtube API -

```
<html>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var ScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, ScriptTag);

var player; 
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {                      
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId : 'YtF6p_w-cSc',                 
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }      
        });
      }       

       function onPlayerReady(event) {                                        
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {   
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {   
            player.loadVideoById ('4MJRS-cLozU');
        }       
      }

</script>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

**Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onmqef11/)**

**Description -**

In the above code their are `2 videos` that are played one after the other
 [i.e. initially  `YtF6p_w-cSc` and then `4MJRS-cLozU`]. Now, when the first video is `loaded/played` i want to hide the control
[i.e. `PlayerVar{control : 0}`] below highlighted part in yellow should be eliminated.
[image]

while for the other video i want it back [i.e control:1].

In simple words i want to `hide control` for `1st video` and want it back for the `2nd video`.

How to achieve this. 
Please help.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YtF6p_w-cSc?autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',      
      events: {                
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          } 
    });              
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {   
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {        
     document.getElementById('ytplayer').src ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4MJRS-cLozU?autoplay=1&controls=1&enablejsapi=1"
        }       
      }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that you used `control=0/1` in the url, I thought that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Add `controls=0` to the end of the url.

To re-enable controls use `controls=1`or 2.

In your configuration add in the same area as your other attributes and events:

```
      playerVars: {
        controls: '0'
      },
```

To re-enable controls use:

```
      playerVars: {
        controls: '1' //or 2 
      },
```

Snippet isn't fully functional due to strict sandbox. Try [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/CeZRDnE8TqAwD2qHBqGE/)

Make your iframe manually and change the url. Do not try changing `playerVars` the only option Youtube allows to be changed dynamically in `playerVars` is captions.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/ir2qcPwZFdQ?controls=0&enablejsapi=1&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/ir2qcPwZFdQ?color=white&enablejsapi=1&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0" width="560" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<div id="player"></div>
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?controls=0";
  var ScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, ScriptTag);

  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'YtF6p_w-cSc',
      playerVars: {    //<===============================]HERE]
        controls: '0',
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
      player.loadVideoById('4MJRS-cLozU');
    }
  }
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've tried adding `controls=0` at the end of the `URL` but it does not work. Seek bar shows...

Comment: Updated to show that `controls=0` works for url of iframe. `playerVars` is namespaced in `YT`. you must hack `iframe_api` to access `YTConfig`. Too much work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, what i want to achieve is different than what you have mentioned. Let me clear, i want 2 videos to be played, for the 1st video controls should be disabled, and for the 2nd video, control should appear. These videos should be played one after the another.

Comment: Um... you can't figure that part out? Did you cut and paste your code? I mean it's ok if you did, everyone got to start from the beginning. I need to know your level of understanding. I don't want to waste time trying to to explain how to run and hop when I should really explain to you how to crawl and walk.

Comment: `enablejsapi` really should be enabled by default, some of Youtube API is wacked. Well that's excellent, sir happy coding.